# Who wins the straight or do they split the pot

Tags: texas-hold-em

A  K  Q  J  10 on table
Player 1 has 8 9
Player two has  A K
Do they split pot or does someone win

Comment: The pot is split.

Answer (score 0):

Split pot, one player plays the board and since the other player can only make the same hand and not beat the straight then it gets split since they both make the same 5 card hand, unless one player had a flush but i'm assuming not